# Overlap other views on Camera Preview in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm following the Android developer's guide for the Camera API (Using v1 right now). I can't find a way to overlap a view (in my case an imagebutton/imageview on top of the preview). I'm using a frameLayout. Here's the layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blackfruit.camfilters.CameraActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
     android:layout_weight="1">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:src="@drawable/snap"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      />

 </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know there are other ways like for example using a surfaceview and linearlayout. But I'm figuring out the problem with this approach. I've seen people saying this works completely however mine doesn't meaning I just see the camera preview and not any buttons or image overlapping it.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "mine doesn't" means.

Comment: Sorry added. To be clear, all i see is the preview and not my imageview overlaying it.

Answer (score 0):

With trial and error. I somehow managed to solve the issue. I used `myImageView.bringToFront();`

which eventually solved the problem.